# Alias doesn't work inside a Bash script

Tags: bash, sh, alias

I have an executable file command.sh

```
#/bin/bash
alias my_command='echo ok'
my_command
```

My terminal is bash.

When I run it like `./command.sh`, it works fine.

When I run it like `/bin/bash ./command.sh`, it can't find a my_command executable.

When I run it like `/bin/sh ./command.sh`, it works fine.

I'm confused here. Where's the problem?

Comment: "My terminal is bash." No, your *shell* is bash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the `bash` man page:

> Aliases  are  not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the `expand_aliases` shell option is set using `shopt` (see the
>          description of `shopt` under **SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS** below).

In other words, aliases are not enabled in bash shell scripts by default. When you run the script with `bash`, it fails.

Your `sh` appears to default to allowing aliases in scripts. When you run the script with `sh`, it succeeds.

`./command.sh` happens to work because your shebang is malformed (you're missing the `!` in `#!/bin/bash`).

Comment: Later in the same section: "For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases." I never realized that aliases aren't expanded in non-interactive shells. That's one more reason to avoid them. Bash aliases seem quite crippled relative to csh/tcsh aliases. On the other hand, csh/tcsh doesn't have functions.

Comment: Actually, I come to this question trying to simplify another one - why my aliases from /etc/bash.bashrc, or from ~/profile doesn't being used. So function isn't an option here.

Comment: Also I'm doing `shopt -s expand_aliases` before executing, or even on the same line like `shopt -s expand_aliases; ...` but it still doesn't get it.

Comment: @IgorLoskutov There are two shells at work: your interactive shell, and the shell that is started to run your script. Setting this option in your interactive shell will not work, since that's not the shell your script uses. You have to put the `shopt -s expand_aliases` in your script.

Comment: @IgorLoskutov: Is replacing all your aliases by functions an option?

Comment: @IgorLoskutov. I came here with the same problem - the alias expansion stops working in the bash script, even after `shopt -s expand_aliases` has been set at the top of the file. It works for a few lines, and then later stops working. I put `shopt -s expand_aliases` before the lines which aren't working, yet bash doesn't expand them. It looks like "aliases are not intended for script files - use functions instead" is the rule. BTW, the section is nested twice, in a `for` loop and then `if`. I tried unindenting the `alias=` back to the first column, but no joy.

Answer (score 6):

Aliases are for the interactive shell, what you want here is a function, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
function my_command() {
    echo ok
}

my_command
```

Comment: The POSIX-compliant function declaration syntax is just `my_command() {`, with no `function` preceding; the `function` keyword exists for backwards compatibility with ancient ksh, which uses `function my_command {` with no `()`. Combining the ksh and POSIX formats gets you a result that's compatible with neither; see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete